# I can't figure out how to set the correct button to be unhidden using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to create a quiz app for a project, I'm having a problem when I try to set another button to be revealed when you select the correct answer. ex.

1+2=?

2
3
5
9

When they select 3, I want the continue button to appear to go to the next page.

```
@IBAction func Seaturtle(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 2 {
        7.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: use animation on continue button. Keep that hidden first and then make it appear in animation

Comment: I've hidden the continue button, I just need the code to make it appear when the correct answer is selected.

Comment: I guess you have written that code yourself where you are making it as unhidden. `continue.hidden = false`

Comment: So how do I give the continue button that label? I tried giving it a tag but when I use it I get the error "Value of type 'int' has no member 'hidden'."

Comment: first of all what is `7.hidden = false` what is `7` here. `7` is a number has no property called `hidden`

Comment: 7 is the tag for the continue button

Comment: you can't use like that. You cant use int with hidden property..you have to write `continueButton.hidden = false` where `continueButton` is the name of your continue button

Comment: How would I use the name of the button instead of the tag? Like how would I label the button to be "continue" so I could use,    continue.hidden = false

Comment: If I just use continueButton.hidden = false, I get "Use of unresolved identifier 'continueButton'. So how would I identify it to be "continueButton"

Comment: You can drag a `UIButton`, provide a outlet, name as `continueButton` or something and provide the `.hidden = false`. Keep that button hidden earlier

Comment: Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Storyboard and find the `Continue` button you wish to hide/unhide. Use Xcode's split screen view to have both your Storyboard and the associated code file open. Select the button, then `Ctrl+Drag` from the button into the code, creating an `IBOutlet` instead of an `IBAction`. Say you give it the name `continueButton`. Then, when you want to hide/unhide just call

```
continueButton.hidden = true
```

or

```
continueButton.hidden = false
```